# PHP / SQL When I split results to pages, only 1st page results is shown

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination, xampp

I am trying to display my history of cash records in rows of 25 per page, but as I exceeds 25 records, only 1st page is displayed. When I click to other page(s) the result, as well as the page numbers disappear.

I am currently on XAMPP (localhost).

My DB table is as follows

**id int(11)**

**date varchar(15)**

**detail varchar(75)**

**amount varchar(9)**

**type varchar(5)**

**recorded_by varchar(75)**

PLEASE IGNORE THE CLASS IN HTML TAGS AS I AM USING BOOTSTRAP.

`$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydb");#No password used.`

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;

$query = "SELECT * FROM cash_record ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);


?>
<p class='h3 text-center'>
    Cash / Bank History
</p>
<table class='table table-sm'>
<thead class='table-dark'>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Detail <sup>[type]</sup></th>
        <th class='text-right'>Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
$rows[] = $row;
}
foreach($rows as $row)
{
    if($row['detail'] == "Expense / Purchases Paid"){
        $class = "table-warning";
    }else{
        $class = "";
    }
    echo "<tr class='$class' title='Recorded by: ".$row['recorded_by']."'>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['detail']."<sup><small> [".$row['type']."]</small></sup>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td class='text-right'>";
    echo number_format((float)$row['amount'], 2, '.', '');
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM cash_record";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$total_pages = ceil($row["total"] / $results_per_page); // calculate total pages with results
echo "<div class='text-center lead'><small>Page: ";
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
            echo "<a class='btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm' href='cash_history.php?page=".$i."'";
            echo ">".$i."</a> "; 
}
```

Comment: A good Example of pagination: https://codeshack.io/how-to-create-pagination-php-mysql/

Comment: I noticed that you are using $results_per_page variable, but it didn't initialized yet.

Comment: The good news is you are using mysqli, but you didn't utilized it to prevent your application from most prominent web attack SQL Injection. So please use mysqli  parameterized prepared statements

Comment: houssam -> It worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Hardood -> Sorry, that part was missed when I copied my code. It was like this `$result_per_page = 25;`

And about sql injection prevention, I will update it. Thank you very much.